# Pandas exits early before I can read entire Excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm trying to read in a Python excel file into Pandas, access particular columns of each row, and geocode an address to coordinates. Then write them to a csv

The geocoding part works good, and as far as I know my loop starts out good where it can read the address. However, it just stops as 22 rows. I have no clue why, I've been using Pandas with this same excel file for something else and it does fine. Just doing this, not so much. It has 27k rows in it. Printing out `data.__len__()` gives me `27395`. Any help?

```
##### READ IN DATA
file = r'rollingsales_manhattan.xls'
# Read in the data from the Excel
data = pd.read_excel(file)

# g = geocoder.osm(str(data['ADDRESS'].iloc[0]) + " New York City, NY " + str(data['ZIP CODE'].iloc[0]))


with open("geotagged_manhattan.csv", 'wb') as result_file:
    wr = csv.writer(result_file)
    for index,d in enumerate(data):
        print(str(data['ADDRESS'].iloc[index]) + " New York City, NY " + str(data['ZIP CODE'].iloc[index]))
```

Then my output...

```
345 WEST 14TH   STREET                    New York City, NY 10014
345 WEST 14TH   STREET                    New York City, NY 10014
345 WEST 14TH   STREET                    New York City, NY 10014
345 WEST 14TH   STREET                    New York City, NY 10014
345 WEST 14TH   STREET                    New York City, NY 10014
345 WEST 14TH   STREET                    New York City, NY 10014
345 WEST 14TH   STREET                    New York City, NY 10014
345 WEST 14TH   STREET                    New York City, NY 10014
345 WEST 14TH   STREET                    New York City, NY 10014
345 WEST 14TH   STREET                    New York City, NY 10014
345 WEST 14TH   STREET                    New York City, NY 10014
345 WEST 14TH   STREET                    New York City, NY 10014
345 WEST 14TH   STREET                    New York City, NY 10014
345 WEST 14TH   STREET                    New York City, NY 10014
345 WEST 14TH   STREET                    New York City, NY 10014
345 WEST 14TH   STREET                    New York City, NY 10014
345 WEST 14TH   STREET                    New York City, NY 10014
229 EAST 2ND   STREET                     New York City, NY 10009
243 EAST 7TH   STREET                     New York City, NY 10009
238 EAST 4TH   STREET                     New York City, NY 10009
303 EAST 4TH STREET                       New York City, NY 10009

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `iteritems()` method to iterate over the Pandas series. To iterate them both, use map() like such...

```
with open("geotagged_manhattan.csv", 'wb') as result_file:
    wr = csv.writer(result_file)
    for a, z in map(None, data['ADDRESS'].iteritems(), data['ZIP CODE'].iteritems()):
        print(str(a[1]) + " New York City, NY " + str(z[1]))
```